# No me aparece la opción de importar las librerias en selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Holas soy nuevo en selenium y no me esta apareciendo la opción de importar las librerias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me deberia aparecer esta opción pero no me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda